# Convert CSV to JSON

Tags: export, output-formatting, data, associations, json-format

I'd like to convert some csv data to json.

The CSV:

```
data={{"imo", "Name", "connectorManufacturer", "connectorDesign", "Size", "Rating", "Manufacturer", "ConnectorDesign", "AdapterManufacturer", "rSize", "AdapterDesign"}, {5171189, "AI", "Cam", "Model 70", 18.75, 10000, "Cameron; GE V", "ExF H4", "GE V", 20, ""}, {9705093, "AH", "Cam", "", 18.75, 15000, "", "", "AS", 21, ""}}
```

I would like this outputted to the following json format:

```
    datajson= {
{
       "imo": 5171189,
       "Name": "AI",
       "connectorManufacturer": "Cam ",
       "connectorDesign": "Model 70",
       "Size": 18.75,
       "Rating": 10000,
       "Manufacturer": "Cam; GE V",
       "ConnectorDesign": "ExF H4",
       "AdapterManufacturer": "GE V",
       "rSize": 20,
       "AdapterDesign": ""
     },
     {
       "imo": 9705093,
       "Name": "AH",
       "connectorManufacturer": "Cam",
       "connectorDesign": "",
       "Size": 18.75,
       "Rating": 15000,
       "Manufacturer": "",
       "ConnectorDesign": "",
       "AdapterManufacturer": "AS",
       "rSize": 21,
       "AdapterDesign": ""
     }
}
```

I have tried to export to json format but this doesn't produce the result above that I'm trying achieve.

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Does this work? ``ExportString[Thread[data[[1]] -> #] & /@ data[[2 ;;]], "JSON"]``

Comment: That works great - thanks for your help!

Comment: I've just realised that your solution works for nearly all of the data for some reason any number with a decimal point is altered. For example '18.75' becomes '1.875e1'. Any idea why this is or how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Two possible solutions. Either do not convert to numeric values when importing from CSV: ``data = Import[..., "CSV", "Numeric" -> False]``, or manually set precision when exporting to JSON: ``ExportString[SetPrecision[..., 10], "JSON"]``.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Domen. Your first solution works best but only problem now is that all of the numbers are appearing as string with "" around them. Is there a way to turn them back to numerical format but also still with good decimal format? This data will be sent to an API which expects the numbers to be in numerical format not as strings if you understand?